# Is it possible to place a Kudan ARCameraViewController inside a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, react-native, kudan

I want to use Kudan inside an existing React-Native App. You can create your own Native Components in React-Native so I thought I could make a Kudan-component.

In React-Native I have to write a function which returns a UIView, RN can place on the screen. But all tutorials about Kudan tell me to make my UIViewController into an ARCameraViewController which I can't do because of all the other RN-Components.

I tried the following (YTARViewController extends ARCameraViewController):

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  UIViewController* controller = [[YTARViewController alloc] init];
  UIView* view = [[ARCameraView alloc] init];
  controller.view = view;
  return view;
}
```

But this renders my app unresponsive with 100% CPU usage as soon as I instantiate this component from JS, which will run above code and try to place the view on screen, which doesn't happen, because the app is already unresponsive at this point.

Comment: I found a first solution by now. The problem was that I put the controller into a local variable, so I lost any reference to it, when the function terminated and it was garbage collected. When I keep a reference to the controller, the Camera shows up inside React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  UIViewController* controller = [[YTARViewController alloc] init];
  UIView* view = [[ARCameraView alloc] init];
  [controller.view addSubview: view];
 \\ view.frame = assign frame here.
  return view;
}
```